# How to run rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have an existing .rake file. It used to have one task and I added one more task to the existing rake file.

But when I try to run, it throws an error:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task ___
```

`abc.rake` file:

```
namespace abcd
  namespace abcde
    task pqr do
      ------------------
    end

    task mno do ( new task which I added)
     ---------------------
    end
  end
end
```

But when I used command: `rake abcd:abcde:mno` -- it showed above error

So I used `rake -T -A` , I am able to see the rake task `abcd:abcde:pqr` but am unable to see the other one.

I am new to rails. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if your rake task is wrong, it won't be findable. Make sure your rake task is correct. First delete the meat of `task mno` or just have a simple `puts` in there and then run rake -T. See if it shows up then.

Comment: I tried that. Didn't work. Still missing mno task. Please tell me how to import rake task?

Comment: do you need to restart your spring server?

Comment: I restarted the server. But still same error

Comment: Please refer this [document](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks)

Answer (score 17):

Here what you exactly want.....

Inside lib/tasks create file abcd.rake

Write the following code inside abcd.rake file

```
namespace :abcd do
  namespace :abcde do

     task :pqr do
       puts 'Inside PQR'
     end

     task :new_added_task do
       puts 'Inside New Added Task'
     end

     task :mno => [:new_added_task]  do
       puts 'Inside Mno'
     end

   end
end
```

Now try following commands....

```
rake abcd:abcde:pqr           #  Output => Inside PQR 

rake abcd:abcde:mno           #  Output => Inside New Added Task
                              #            Inside Mno

rake abcd:abcde:new_added_task  # Output => Inside New Added Task
```

To view all tasks run command

```
rake -T -A
```

It will show all tasks along with your own created tasks...

```
rake abcd:abcde:mno                                 # 
rake abcd:abcde:new_added_task                      # 
rake abcd:abcde:pqr                                 # 
.............
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:
Have you tried prepending the command with 'bundle exec'? 
Ex: `~$ bundle exec rake abcd:abcde:mno`

If you have multiple versions in your gem file you'll often need to run bundle exec to run the command using your current project directory's gems.

(Optional) Step 2:
If that fails try specifying the environment like this
Ex: `~$ bundle exec rake abcd:abcde:mno RAILS_ENV=development`

Answer (score 1):

Here is test code for you:

create a file abcde.rake under ../lib/tasks/abcde.rake

```
namespace :abcde do
  desc 'pqr pqr pqr pqr'
  task :pqr => :environment do
    puts 'pqr'
  end
  desc 'mno mno mno mno'
  task :mno => :environment do
     puts 'mno'
  end
end
```

Then run this command

```
rake -T
```

output of above command is:

```
rake abcde:mno                                   # mno mno mno mno
rake abcde:pqr                                   # pqr pqr pqr pqr
```

Run

```
rake abcde:mno #mno
```

Comment: Hi.. I followed exact process. But output of command is not displaying rake abcde:mno. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: please try this code as it is in your project , some time there is a minor issue that we are missing. I have created and run this in my project before answer you.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 6.x you have to use rails instead of rake.
The example from user400617 above

```
namespace :abcd do
  namespace :abcde do

     task :pqr do
       puts 'Inside PQR'
     end

     task :new_added_task do
       puts 'Inside New Added Task'
     end

     task :mno => [:new_added_task]  do
       puts 'Inside Mno'
     end

   end
end
```

would be run like this

```
rails abcd:abcde:pqr           #  Output => Inside PQR 

rails abcd:abcde:mno           #  Output => Inside New Added Task
                              #            Inside Mno

rails abcd:abcde:new_added_task  # Output => Inside New Added Task
```

Took me a while to figure this out.